# How to setup real-time updates subscription for user checkins in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Since March 2012 facebook user_ckechins permissions field is replaced with user_status.
When subscribing to object "user" field "checkins" using facebook API, you will be successfully subscribed, but will not receive any updates to your endpoint url!!!

You have to subscribe to object "user" field "status" to receive checking with real-time updates, althouth this is not documented in [facebook real-time updates api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).

Comment: And your question is? - If you think the information is useful to share, please look up the question yours is the answer to and answer there. Or formulate a question your own and answer it then.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

RTUs have changed over the years. The current (Nov 2013) way to get user checkins and status messages is to enable 'feed' in the RTU subscription.